# Changing the NatTable color

Tags: java, eclipse, nattable

I am trying to grey-out/disable the entire NatTable upon a if condition.
What I'm trying to achieve here is similar to the setenabled(false) function in a regular table.

So Far I have found out that the configRegistry needs to be changed it must be added to the NatTable but i'm unsure how to proceed with this.

Comment: write something in an easy way so that people who are trying to help can understand easily. Your efforts, targets, so far results etc.

Answer (score 0):

Styling in NatTable is done via the ConfigRegistry. Typically this is done at creation time or conditionally via config labels. In your use case you need to programmatically access the ConfigRegistry via `NatTable#getConfigRegistry()` and change the base styles via API.